# Botframework V4 - How to end conversation?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

How can I end a conversation in Microsoft Bot Framework v4 (in C#)? 
I use a few different states that are persisted to CosmosDB in Azure.
I want my bot to return to that state, so when a user messages the bot again, it replies with the welcome message.

I've tried to copy the v3 way of doing it but I didn't succeed

```
var msg = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
msg.Type = ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation;
msg.AsEndOfConversationActivity().Code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully;

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(msg, cancellationToken);
```

The result of that is:

> [18:11:27]<-endOfConversation
>
> [18:11:27]POST200conversations.replyToActivity
>
> [18:11:27]POST200directline.postActivity

It kind of ended the conversation but it didn't clear the states.

Answer (score 3):

The C# v4 SDK now uses endDialogAsync() and cancelAllDialogAsync() to help manage the dialog state.

endDialogAsync() ends the current dialog on the stack returning control to the parent dialog, if present, or to the turn handler. Additionally, it can be called from anywhere the dialog context is accessible. Best practice is to call it at the end of every dialog.

cancelAllDialogAsync() removes all dialogs from the stack.

Here is a snippet taken from the BotBuilder-Samples Basic-Bot [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/942484792509495f39fa020c7eb9b501d42f0433/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot/BasicBot.cs#L108) showing both utilized as part of the OnTurnAsyc process:

```
// if no one has responded,
if (!dc.Context.Responded)
{
    // examine results from active dialog
    switch (dialogResult.Status)
    {
        case DialogTurnStatus.Empty:
            switch (topIntent)
            {
                case GreetingIntent:
                    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(GreetingDialog));
                    break;

                case NoneIntent:
                    default:
                    // Help or no intent identified, either way, let's provide some help.
                    // to the user
                    await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("I didn't understand what you just said to me.");
                    break;
                    }

                    break;

                 case DialogTurnStatus.Waiting:
                    // The active dialog is waiting for a response from the user, so do nothing.
                    break;

                case DialogTurnStatus.Complete:
                    await dc.EndDialogAsync();
                    break;

                default:
                    await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
                    break;
            }
     }
}
```

To restart a conversation/dialog, you will need to implement an activity on ConversationUpdate, ConversationRelationUpdate, etc. Please be aware that this is channel specific meaning each channel determines on what method it will be triggered.

Again, this snippet shows how it is implemented on the OnTurnAsync process:

```
// Processes ConversationUpdate Activities to welcome the user.
else if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded != null)
        {
            await SendWelcomeMessageAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Lastly, there is a 'delete' method that can be called on your state accessors. Look over [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/942484792509495f39fa020c7eb9b501d42f0433/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/GraphAuthenticationBot.cs#L236) that shows how state is being cleared.

Hope of help!

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your response. I need to change my code to try it, so that it uses a dialog rather than just simple user input. I will try it once I implement the dialog. thank you

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue. The bot won't resend the welcome message. I am not sure what you mean by saying to implement an activity on ConversationUpdate. Thanks